# jQuery - find element and show or hide

Tags: jquery

I have the following markup:

```
<footer class="form__footer">
     <div class="form__actions">
       <div class="form__action form__action--primary">
           <button class="button button--chevron-right button--primary" 
                   name="next" 
                   type="submit" 
                   value="Next">Next
            </button>
       </div>
       <div class="form__action form__action--secondary">
              <button class="button button--chevron-left button--standout" 
                      name="back" 
                      type="submit" 
                      value="Previous">Previous
             </button>
       </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

I want show/hide the next button when value of a dropdown changes. The following throws jquery syntax error: `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: button, input[type='submit', name='next']`

```
$( "footer.form__footer" ).find("button, input[type='submit', name='next']").hide();
```

The following hides both buttons:

```
$( "footer.form__footer" ).find("button, input[type='submit'][ name='next']").hide();
```

What is the correct syntax to hide only the next button?

Comment: You don't have any `input`s in your HTML.. why are you trying to select one?

Answer (score 1):

Why you're referencing an input when you have a button, use :

```
$( "footer.form__footer" ).find("button[name='next']").hide();
```

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $("footer.form__footer").find("button[name='next']").hide();
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<footer class="form__footer">
  <div class="form__actions">
    <div class="form__action form__action--primary">
      <button class="button button--chevron-right button--primary" name="next" type="submit" value="Next">Next
            </button>
    </div>
    <div class="form__action form__action--secondary">
      <button class="button button--chevron-left button--standout" name="back" type="submit" value="Previous">Previous
             </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Ok I've figured it out:

```
$( "footer.form__footer" ).find("button[name='next']").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to find a `button` or `input` element from the DOM. You can try the followings. This will hide matching elements from the target container

```js
$( "footer.form__footer" ).find("button[type='submit'][ name='next'], input[type='submit'][ name='next']").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer class="form__footer">
     <div class="form__actions">
       <div class="form__action form__action--primary">
           <button class="button button--chevron-right button--primary" 
                   name="next" 
                   type="submit" 
                   value="Next">Next
            </button>
       </div>
       <div class="form__action form__action--secondary">
              <button class="button button--chevron-left button--standout" 
                      name="back" 
                      type="submit" 
                      value="Previous">Previous
             </button>
       </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your buttons contains only a certain word you also can use `:contains` selector to hide only the `buttons` which contains the word `Next`:

```js
$("footer.form__footer button:contains('Next')").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<footer class="form__footer">
  <div class="form__actions">
    <div class="form__action form__action--primary">
      <button class="button button--chevron-right button--primary" name="next" type="submit" value="Next">Next
            </button>
    </div>
    <div class="form__action form__action--secondary">
      <button class="button button--chevron-left button--standout" name="back" type="submit" value="Previous">Previous
             </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: @adam78 Check my answer

Comment: better to use the `name=` attribute as the UI text may change, but that should not (eg for localisation).  (not required, just "better" practice)